# how to parse with jquery the id from a uri like http://beta.domo.md/ro/smartphones/159-philips-s388-android.html (id=159)?

Tags: jquery, parsing

how to parse with jquery the id from a url like

"http://beta.domo.md/ro/smartphones/159-philips-s388-android.html" (id=159)

or

"/ro/smartphones/159-philips-s388-android.html" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help, try it:

```
var url="http://beta.domo.md/ro/smartphones/159-philips-s388-android.html";
var url1=url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
var id=url1.substring(0, url1.indexOf("-"));
```

Comment: What if there's one more `-` before page name? (i.e. `smartphones` might be like`smart-phones`.)

Comment: @MokshShah How about now?

Comment: Check again... still it returns `/159` instead of `159`.

Comment: how about my one-liner answer ?

Answer (score 2):

```
function parseUrl( url ) {
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.href = url;
   return a;
}

parseUrl('beta.domo.md/ro/smartphones/159-philips-s388-android.html?img_id=33').search
```

Comment: Have you verified your answer before posting ?
and from where did you get this `?img_id=33` in `URL` ?

Answer (score 2):

**How about this:**

```js
    var url="http://beta.domo.md/ro/smartphones/159-philips-s388-android.html";
alert(url.split('/').pop().split('-')[0]);
```